# nuxt (2) no loaders are configured to process this file (@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb)

Tags: webpack, amazon-dynamodb, nuxt.js

Getting error:

```
These dependencies were not found:
nuxt02  |
nuxt02  | * @aws-sdk/client-dynamodb in ./middleware/checkForRedirect.js
nuxt02  | * @aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb in ./middleware/checkForRedirect.js
```

[image: screen shot of above report]

I have these dependencies installed in package.json:

[image: screenshot of dependencies, supposedly in package.json]

Using nuxt version 2.0.0.

The node_modules folder has these libs installed:
[image: screenshot of libraries shown from library root node_modules down]

The import statement (inside middleware):
(from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.ReadItem.html)

[image: screenshot of imports in checkForRedirect.js]

Why is the nuxt compiler throwing these errors?

Update: OK turns out the npm install on the docker container wasn't doing a full install (using cached info). That part is OK (libs found).

New errors however:
[image: screenshot of additional errors reported]

I have found someone with a similar issue here:[Error when using s3-sync-client and @aws-sdk/client-s3 with webpack in Electron project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75811777/error-when-using-s3-sync-client-and-aws-sdk-client-s3-with-webpack-in-electron)

And I am using the accepted answer (they are not using Nuxt however!) to try and get this thing to build:

[image: screenshot of nuxt.config.js]

(does not work, still getting same error)

Comment: please do not use images to show code or logs.

Comment: ok noted. Was purely for formatting reasons (the editor's format for logs was pretty unreadable)

Comment: You should use [Syntax highlighting for code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting). Images make it difficult to copy the code or the error and investigate about it, and that causes almost no one to be interested in responding.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your import statement, it should be like this:

```
import { DynamoDBClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";
```

For the lib-dynamodb make sure you also have `@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb` installed as it a separate package.

Comment: Sorry that typo was somehow introduced before making post. Fixed the typo (error still same as before).
Both lib-dynamodb and client-dynamodb are installed (as can be seen from the node_modules folder)